# TFS Query KeywordSearch in c#

Tags: c#

i am using below query but the problem is with "Does Not Contain". it is giving error

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(
                  new Uri("http://abc1.com"));
                WorkItemStore workItemStore = (WorkItemStore)tpc.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore));
                WorkItemCollection rdIncidentqueryResults = workItemStore.Query("Select [State], [Title]  From WorkItems Where [Work Item Type] = 'Task' AND ([State] <> 'Resolved' AND [State] <> 'Closed') AND [Assigned to] = 'Test' AND [KeywordSearch] Does Not Contain 'test1'");
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: {" Expecting comparison operator. The error is caused by «'Does Not Contain'»."}

Comment: I tried with 'Does Not Contain' and \"Does Not Contain\" but no luck

Comment: @User, you can edit the post to include these details into the message body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be `NOT CONTAINS` instead of `Does Not Contain`.  You can use Visual Studio to construct a TFS query for you and save the output to file as a .wiq file and see what syntax is valid.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Adam Caviness